# Converting File to Protobuf Message

Tags: java, file, message, protocol-buffers

I have an xml file which I want to send as a com.google.protobuf.Message:

```
File file = new File("first.xml");
Message message1 = (Message) ir.sendRawFile(file);
```

But I can't cast java.io.File to com.google.protobuf.Message

This is the method:

```
public File sendRawFile(File file)
    {
        return file;    
    }
```

How do I do that??

Comment: You can't. You need to define (or have you already?) a message format that contains the content of the file as well as required metadata & send that. Make a File object like that Person object in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: You either need to explicitly parse the XML and explicitly convert it to a protocol buffer message, or you could just dump the bytes of the file into a dumb protocol buffer message that just contains some bytes, which kind of ruins the point of using protocol buffers in the first place, but that might be sufficient if you just need protobufs just because.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm parsing the XML using JAXB. What do I do next? I don't really know how to use protobufs. I need to send this xml file as a string and publish it to Solace.